# How to combine two LAN that going through the same Modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have T-Mobile Home Internet and it's receiver is the Arcadyan KVD21.  This receiver has two ethernet out ports.  I connected my Asus wireless router to the first port.  The wireless router is where all of my devices are except for my desktop-pc.  The wireless router default gateway is 192.168.50.1.  I connect my desktop-pc directly to the second port of the Arcadyan.  This prints out the default gateway of 192.168.12.1.  From my desktop-pc, I can't access any devices that connected to the Asus router.  Is there a way to set it up so that I can access the devices on Asus network from my desktop-pc?

Comment: Yes; Both ports should be on the same 192.168.50.x subnet, the wireless DHCP subnet can of course be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your inputs.  After reading all of the suggestions about being on the "same subnet", setting the router to be a "switch", etc.  I was able to use Bing chat to ask it "How to set up Asus router as a switch".  It did suggest to turn the Asus router into an "Access Point", which ended up putting the main Asus router on to the same subnet as my desktop, which is 192.168.12.x.  My other mesh nodes are still intact and I can now access everything.  The Access Point mode did turn off the Asus router firewall, IP sharing, and NAT functions.  I don't know how important those are.

Answer (score 1):

Your Asus router is most likely using NAT (Network Address Translation) protocol to isolate the network it provides. NAT allows a router to have only one IP address showing to the Internet (or the next-higher router) while connecting multiple IP address below it. A side effect of NAT is the clients in the outer network cannot initiate connections into the inner network.

This prevents your wired PC from accessing anything on your wireless network.

Assuming that your KVD21 provides NAT to its Ethernet ports, you may be able to set up your Asus router to transparent bridge mode so that it does not do NAT itself. This will put the wired port and the wireless network under the same NAT.

Comment: NAT itself when implemented statefully does not "isolate" the network. If the ASUS router does not have firewall filtering traffics from the WAN side, a route can be added on the PC for its LAN subnet with its WAN IP as the gateway/nexthop. But of course, the easiest way would be to make the ASUS router work merely as a switch so that the devices connected to it would "join" the "outer" broadcast domain, and hence getting an IP from the DHCP server there and hence be in the same IP subnet as the PC, in which case the PC will not need additional route to reach them.

Comment: @TomYan NAT does isolate in the sense that multiple IP address on the inter network come out all using the same IP address on the outer network, using different port numbers (mapped to the inner IP address/port by NAT). A device on the outside simply cannot address a device on the inside unless using a mapping for a connection created by NAT. This is excluding NAT funneling which requires additional protocol between routers or setting up static tunneling. Much easier just not to run NAT on the inner router.

Comment: Keyword: stateful; When NAT is implemented in e.g. the way Linux does it, only traffics belong to the "connections" *initiated* from a host *behind* the NAT will have the source address rewritten. Therefore for cases like the OP here, all you need is a proper route configured on the "outside host" and firewall down on the gateway. Feel free to test yourself on a Linux "router" or even some random consumer grade router. (It's at least half of the reason why they need to implement a firewall.)

Comment: @TomYan I'm a newbie at this and so I'm not sure how to make the Asus router to act as a switch.  I can try to look it up.  I'm not sure if this matters or complicates things but I'm actually using AiMesh with the Asus routers.  If you're not familiar with AiMesh, Asus allows for its wireless routers to connect to each other as a mesh using the AiMesh technology.  I currently have 3 Asus wireless router.  One acts as the main router while the other two are mesh nodes.  I'm not sure where or how to set the main router as a switch so that it doesn't mess up the mesh system.

Comment: @DemDemD as Doxy said, usually you go to the setting portal to make the router work in bridge / AP mode. Some router even has a physical switch for that. Another way is to **disable its DHCP server** and then connect the modem router to one of its LAN ports instead of its WAN port. (Its LAN IP also needs to be changed if their subnet conflicts, which is apparently NOT your case.) No experience Mesh WiFi but I don't suppose the latter approach would break it.